# Olive oil, Canola oil, or almond oil

Tags: frying, steak, olive

Which kind of oil is best to fry steak in a cast-iron skillet with?? Olive, Canola, almond ?? I'm looking for the best taste profile also. Thanks.

Comment: Taste is a matter of opinion; best requires some sort of criteria with which to evaluate.   See related:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/701/what-oil-or-fat-to-use-for-different-purposes?rq=1  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/how-do-you-cook-a-steak-like-those-found-in-fine-steakhouses?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taste is a matter of opinion; best requires some sort of criteria with which to evaluate.   See related:

- [What oil or fat to use for different purposes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/701/what-oil-or-fat-to-use-for-different-purposes?rq=1)
- [How do you cook a steak like those found in fine steakhouses?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/how-do-you-cook-a-steak-like-those-found-in-fine-steakhouses?rq=1)
- [What is meant by "neutral" oils?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/what-is-meant-by-neutral-oils)

Depending on the steak, your preferences,and the cooking method, either canola or olive might be the winner from the selection you have enumerated; almond oil is fairly exotic, at least in the US, and would not normally be used for steak cookery.